# Why doesn't this Elm code work? (Example provided with expected output)

Tags: elm

I'm trying to make an elm program that outputs the following pattern :

```
3 4 2 3 2 4 ...
```

Here is my Elm Code :

```
main =  lift asText agent

delta = lift (\x -> -1) (fps 1)

agent = foldp update 3 delta

update : Int -> Int -> Int
update x y = x + y  + (threshold x)

threshold : Int -> Int

threshold x = if (x < 3) then x
              else 0
```

This is what I think the code should be saying

```
 3 + -1 + 0 = 2
 2 + -1 + 3 = 4
 4 + -1 + 0 = 3
 3 + -1 + 0 = 2 ... etc
```

However this is not the output. I think I'm confused as to how the signals update ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things keeping your code from giving you `3` then `2` then `4` then `3` again. (Which is not exactly what you describe at the start of your question, but you do at the finish so I'll go with that. )

### Argument order of `update`

If you look at the type of `foldp`,

```
foldp : (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Signal a -> Signal b
```

you'll notice that the last value calculated is the *second* argument to the update function you supply. So if you make your `update` function

```
update y x = x + y  + (threshold x)
```

then you should be closer to what you wanted you function to be.

### Meaning of `threshold`

`threshold` returns `x` when `x < 3`, so when the last `x` was `2`, it'll return `2`, so you'll get:

```
3 + -1 + 0 = 2
2 + -1 + 2 = 3
3 + -1 + 0 = 2
2 + -1 + 2 = 3
```

Now I'm not sure what you're after but if you add a `+1` to `threshold` you should get close to the output you were expecting.

### Conclusion

With these changes your code would look like:

```
main =  lift asText agent

delta = lift (\x -> -1) (fps 1)

agent = foldp update 3 delta

update : Int -> Int -> Int
update y x = x + y  + (threshold x)

threshold : Int -> Int

threshold x = if (x < 3) then x+1
              else 0
```